# How to solving for t in the first order derivative of a Fourier Synthesis.

Tags: fourier-analysis

How can I solve for $t$ given,

$$
0 = \frac{2\Pi}{T} \sum_{k=1}^N k(a_k cos(2\Pi\frac{k}{T}t) - b_k sin(2\Pi\frac{k}{T}t))
$$

What I am trying to do is, given a complex wave in the form of a Fourier Series, taking the first order derivative to find all the crests and troughs of the wave within one time period $T$.